# Proguard error while building apk release for android

Tags: android, android-proguard

Error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>   java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\user\Desktop\ProjetsAndroidStudio\v_3\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\user\Desktop\ProjetsAndroidStudio\v_3\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-analytics\8.3.0\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [auc.class == classes.jar:com/google/android/gms/analytics/internal/Command$1.class]))

proguard-rules.pro:

```
-dontpreverify
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic
-dontnote
-repackageclasses ''
-allowaccessmodification
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
-keepattributes Signature,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault

-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

#Configuration de base Android:
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
 public <init>(android.content.Context);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
 public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
 public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity {
public void *(android.view.View);
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
 public void *(android.view.View);
 public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
 public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
 public static **[] values();
 public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

#Pour supprimer les logs lors de la compilation
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
public static int v(...);
public static int d(...);
public static int i(...);
public static int w(...);
public static int e(...);
public static int wtf(...);
}

#Pour que proguard ignore toutes les classes contenues dans un certain package
#Pour la librairie Jackson (parsing JSON)
-keep class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
-dontwarn org.**


#Pour ActionBarSherlock (d'aprËes le site officiel)
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
-keep interface com.actionbarsherlock.** { *; }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find any solution for it? I'm stuck for last 2 days, need help :(

Answer (score -3):

Turning off Minification worked for me when faced with this issue:

In your build.gradle file:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
```

Comment: And why do you use Proguard at all then!? Turning off is not the solution.

Comment: "I'm having problem to start my car." Response: "The problem disappeared after I took a bus instead of a car." :)